# Cannot find my lib on cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I've pushed my lib to cocoapods, this is the log:

```
<code>liuchangdeMacBook-Pro:testScrollAD liuchang$ pod trunk me
  - Name:     ChangLiu
  - Email:    12000290@XX.com
  - Since:    November 23rd, 03:48
  - Pods:
    - DLADFrameWork<code>
  - Sessions:
    - November 23rd, 03:48 - April 13th, 2017 03:28. IP: 106.185.XX.XXX</code>
```

and i can find it on the [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/);
But i when i enter

```
pod search DLFrameWork
```

here is the response

```
[!] Unable to find a pod with name, author, summary, or description matching `DLADFrameWork`
```

I've tried

```
pod setup
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: why do you search DLFrameWrork, but provide an info for DLADFrameWork?

Comment: Don't know if it's you, but please note that the repo owner is using a misspelling: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beautyful

Comment: sorry buddy, i had write wrong word,but i search DLADFrameWork,it still will log these words,cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

try to run

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
```

in terminal.

And then:

```
pod setup
```

again.

Now you should see your searched pod.